Get rendered HTML single view from post template
I'm not new to WordPress but I have a question for the Fullsite Editing / Gutenberg api.
We have a custom template (Single View => Post-Type) designed in the editor as a block theme. And now I want to get the redendered HTML from this template for a specific ID of a post.
So when I request the https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1 I got a not the default post template block rendered content html but the post_content rendered content. So my question is how can I access the detail element (single view) from a custom post type rendered in HTML. So we in classic themes i can easily get this rendered content with get_template_part and the ID of the post.
So how can I access the rendered html content for a single view from a post.
